# Matlab - Haar Wavelet Coefficients calculation - Undefined function 'haart' for input arguments of type 'single'?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, haar-wavelet

I'm running some 16 channel EEG data through feature extraction code.

eegData is a 240000x16 double (240000 samples of EEG data across 16 channels)

```
nc = 16;                                % 16 channels
D = abs(fft(eegData));                  % take FFT of each channel
D(1,:) = 0;                             % set DC component to 0
D = bsxfun(@rdivide,D,sum(D));          % normalize each channel


%% Haar Wavelet Coefficients
haarcoef = zeros(4,16);
for iter1 = 1:nc
    if isnan(sum(D(:,iter1)))
    else
        [haarcoef(:,iter1),~] = haart(D(:,iter1));
    end
end
```

I'm running 60GB of EEG data through this code to train a model and make predicitons on other data. Some of the data files experienced data dropout, so that is why I have the

```
     if isnan(sum(D(:,iter1)))
```

in there.

I'm getting an error:

Undefined function 'haart' for input arguments of type 'single'

on some of the data files, any reason this could be?

Comment: Did you have the wavelet toolbox or the signal analysis toolbox ?

Comment: I have both toolboxes

Comment: it's the input type - make sure that your input matrix is of single precision

Comment: Are the toolboxes installed properly? They should show up in the printed results of `ver`. Also, note that [`haart`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/haart.html) was introduced in MATLAB R2016b.

Comment: @16per9 he's passing it a single precision input, it's explicitly stated in the error message.